# Process a theory in Isabelle/jEdit without saving it

Tags: isabelle

In Isabelle/jEdit, sometimes I want to just test some things in a throw-away theory, without saving it to disk. But when I create a new file (even with the *new in mode* command with mode set to isabelle), the buffer is not processed until I save it (with an appropriate file name).

Is there a way around saving the file? It seems this should be possible, as by default Isabelle/jEdit starts with an empty `Scratch.thy` file which is processed, even if it was not saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isabelle/jEdit seems to use the buffer name to decide whether to process a theory (must end in `.thy`). As far as I know, jEdit does not provide a way to change the name of a buffer without saving it. However, you can open a non-existing file and the resulting buffer will be named after the file.

So, instead of creating a new file, just open a non-existing file (with a name ending in `.thy`, of course) and Isabelle/jEdit will process it, even if not saved to disk.

Comment: Did you really mean `.kbd`?